# Set timer for user input click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check if the user has clicked in an input with in a given time 3 seconds, if not hide the panel.

But my checkInput is not working. If I put it in the main jQuery if just shows for the 3 seconds and then disapears.

My Css is just display:none.

Any help would be good.

```
<div class="sign-up">
            <h4>Login</h4>
            <div class="sign-up-line">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_usr_name" runat="server" Text="User name" /><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_usr_name" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
                                    </div>
            <div class="sign-up-line">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_password" runat="server" Text="Password" /><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_password" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Password"/>
                                    </div>
            <div class="sign-up-text">
             <p>Forgotten your password <a href="#">click here</a></p>
             <p>Problems logging in <a href="#">click here</a></p>
             </div>
            </div>

var signUpPanel = $('.sign-up');
var userName = $('#txt_usr_name');
var password = $('#txt_password');


$('.sign-up-link').on('click', function () {
  if (signUpPanel.is(":hidden")) {
      userName.val('');
      password.val('');

      signUpPanel.slideDown('slow');

      checkInput();

   } else {
          signUpPanel.hide();

   }

});

function checkInput() {
     //set timer
     setTimeout(function () {
        if (userName.val() && password.val()) {
            signUpPanel.hide();
          } else if (!userName.val() && !password.val()) {
            signUpPanel.show();
          }
        }, 3000);
      }
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: In your `checkInput()` function you are hiding the panel if there **IS** a username and password value. Surely you want it the other way round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, it doesn't have any `timer` functions or `delay` functions! So, assuming if there is a code like this:

```
<input id="clickMe" type="submit" value="Click within 3 Secs" />
```

If the user has to click within 3 seconds, you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#clickMe").prop("disabled", true).hide();
    }, 3000);
    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
        clearInterval(a);
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ex600p01/1/

Comment: Yes, that's what you need right? @StudentRik What you want it to do after 3 seconds?

Comment: Okay, so you wanna say if the user clicks it, it should not disappear right?

Comment: Could I do this on the blur event as well?

Comment: @StudentRik yes you can! :)

Comment: For maximum correctness you should be using `clearTimeout` not `clearInterval`. Just sayin' ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at it differently, EG: Hide the panel after 3 seconds *unless* an input is clicked:

```
var signupTimeout = setTimeout(function(){signUpPanel.hide();}, 3000);
signUpPanel.on('click focus', 'input', function () {
    clearTimeout(signupTimeout);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tjhp342j/1/